# Rearranging card on Z axis

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my [portfolio](http://patrykponichtera.com/android.php), i've put some flipping card in it to show my android apps, when someone hover over them they flip and zoom in and show a brief description.

The problem i'm having is that the lower card overlap the above ones when hovered over, i tried using z-index without success

This is the CSS of the cards

```
/* Card */
    .card-wrapper {
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
        -moz-perspective: 1000;
        perspective: 1000;

        border: 1px solid #ccc;

        margin: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        visibility:hidden;
        width:400px;
        height:540px;
        z-index: 2;

    }


        .card-wrapper:hover .flipper, .card-wrapper.hover .flipper {
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.5,1.5) translate(10%, 10%);
            -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2,2);
            transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(2,2);
            position: relative;

        }

    .card-wrapper, .front, .back {

    }

    .flipper {
        -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

        -moz-transition: 0.6s;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

        transition: 0.6s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        height:540px;

        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .front, .back {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        visibility:visible;

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .front {
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .back {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        z-index: 200000000000000000;

    }
```

And this is the HTML

```
<div class="card-wrapper" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <div class="flipper">
                    <div class="front">
                        <!-- front content -->
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="images/wakey-feature.png" alt="Wakey" width="400px" height="450px">
                            <h2 class="app-title">Wakey</h2>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <!-- back content -->
                        <div class="card">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="play-store-card">
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doublep.wakey" target="_blank">
                        <div class="dashed-line">
                            <button class="play-store-button" type="button" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                <img src="images/play-store.png">
                            </button>

                        </div>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z-index won't help you with that, it won't make the div display in front of others divs.

what you need to do is *really* put them in front. One posibility, since you have already a translate in the hover, would be to change it to make the div nearer to you:

instead of

```
.card-wrapper:hover .flipper, .card-wrapper.hover .flipper {
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.5,1.5) translate(10%, 10%);
```

it should be

```
.card-wrapper:hover .flipper, .card-wrapper.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.5,1.5) translate3d(10%, 10%, -100px);
```

and you need to set the preserve 3d in all the elements. I did it with:

```
div {
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

but probably you want to be more precise.
Anyway, with this 2 changes, I think it works ok. (in webkit)

By the way, I would give you a price to the highest z-index ever seen :-)

Comment: Thanks it works, but i have a problem, now the flipper has problems flipping, when i hover on a card it slightly shakes and does nothing, only sometimes it works as it should, do you have some solution for this?
About the z-index i guess i was desperate xD haha

Comment: Ok it works now, i've set the 2 first values of transform to 0

Comment: Good to know !  Nice web, by the way !